# Android Studio working and building project extremely slow on Windows Machine

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I am facing lots of issues in using Android Studio on my Windows machine. (3 years old). The build takes a lot of time. At the same time, Android Studio starts hangin/not responding. Overall it is a pain in the ass. Thing is that my laptop has decent specs.

These are the specs

[image]

Just a few minutes back, after the build took 48 minutes to complete and I was finally starting work again, Studio stopped responding after a while.

[image]

I completely formatted my machine 2 weeks back and have barely any other apps on it. I switched from chrome to Firefox in the hopes that it would improve ram usage and help Studio run better but in vain.

Some things to note. Other people in my office are using the same project. We have optimized the gradle settings etc to ensure fast builds. I have the same gradle files, gradle.properties file which have many optimizations, yet it takes a lot of time on my machine only.

I also disabled VCS and a bunch of other things in order to improve the performance as I saw in some other answers but I still face these issues.

The only problem I can see is that I have HDD instead of SSD and I am not sure if that is causing all the pain? Is there anything I can do to continue development. I am at the point of just ordering a Mac since I was given one at my previous job and it never caused any issues despite being a MacBook Air and not even pro.

Comment: Hi varunkr, I had the same problem. I replaced my HDD with an SDD and I got a great improvement. I recommend you to buy an SSD with at least 250 GB capacity and replace your DVD-RW with your old HDD then install your Windows, JDK, Android SDK on SSD and also save your project on that SSD too. you will get a very great improvement.

Comment: What I have noticed so far: 1) You have a large page file, which is stored on slow HDD, and used when you are lacking RAM (and you are as you can see). Solution: add more ram (yes, 8 GB is probably not enough). 2) The HDD becomes slower over time, and can cause problems. Solution: upgrade to SSD.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thanks for the response. I upgraded to SSD and the build times have reduced significantly. I'd say they are 25% of the build times earlier. Do you think that at this point increasing the RAM to say 16GB further reduce the build time? My laptop is functioning very well now even with Android Studio running while earlier it used to freeze a lot.

Comment: @varunkr check the RAM consumption now. If it is still high (90+%), then it makes sense to upgrade to 16 if possible. SSD is fast, but way not as fast as RAM is

Answer (score 0):

Your system specs are pretty good i'm a windows user and i never face any problems with android studio you should consider uninstalling and downloading the latest version from official website if still problem persists visit this website and apply solution as suggested that's our last hope!

https://medium.com/@Albert348/is-your-android-studio-too-slow-4baae2d0f32c